# How to add properties to JSON log when using JsonFormatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging

In ASP.NET, [`JsonFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#json) can produce output like this

```
{
  "Timestamp": "02:28:21 ",
  "EventId": 14,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Category": "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime",
  "Message": "Now listening on: https://localhost:5001",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Now listening on: https://localhost:5001",
    "address": "https://localhost:5001",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "Now listening on: {address}"
  }
}
```

but I want to add some custom properties at the root level of JSON,

```
{
    "Timestamp": "02:28:21 ",
    "EventId": 14,
    "LogLevel": "Information",
    "Category": "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime",
    "Message": "Now listening on: https://localhost:5001",
    "State": {
      "Message": "Now listening on: https://localhost:5001",
      "address": "https://localhost:5001",
      "{OriginalFormat}": "Now listening on: {address}"
    },
    "RequestId": "f6137a1e-3810-4eba-a4f3-b537b3ae2344",
    "CustomerId": "BD23ECBE-883B-4D96-ACD3-A526933B6D5B",
    "CustomerName": "Contoso"
  }
```

Essentially I want to log my own object `LogMessage` which contains `CustomerName`, `RequestId`, `CustomerId` etc and I want it to merge with the default structure above. Is it possible?

I have looked into ASP.NET source code and I have concluded that it is not possible. I belive nlog can achieve this but assume that I can't use that. What are my alternatives? Third party logging libraries are fine, but I'm looking for solutions other than nlog.

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, it is not possible with the framework-provided `JsonConsoleFormatter`. Checkout [it's implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9ddb7316837cafecceca637dabb1a9b1f2b08409/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/JsonConsoleFormatter.cs#L28) - it writes only [`LogEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.logentry-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) properties at top level.

If you are ok with custom data being added to nested level then you can just use scopes:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(options => options.IncludeScopes = true);
```

and somewhere closer to start of the middleware pipeline:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    var service = ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    using var scope = service.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "ClientId", "TestClient" }
    });
    await next();
});
```

Otherwise you will need to implement [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#implement-a-custom-formatter) which will add all the needed info to the top level logging JSON object.

Alternatively you can look into using [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) with custom enricher.

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer. And I don't think even custom formatter would work because it takes the `LogEntry` as the input. So we can do string manipulation _around_ the message, but not with the message. That is, my object would be present as a string. I guess I can deserialize that message and access its properties, but that would be unperformant.